# Automatically create record while creating a entity record

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I have a `project` entity and a `projectStages` entity. I want, when a project record will be created automatically `projectStages` entities will be created for each stages.Till now I was doing it using plugin.
       Just wanted to know if there is any way I within the CRM to do this.

this is a screen shot of the customer security roll.
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do that using plugins, is there any reason you don't want to use plugins? You could use workflows to create projectstages when a project is created too, that will be asynchronous though.

Comment: Thanks Rickerd,I have created a workflow,but while creating a project its showing `The selected user does not have sufficient privileges to be assigned records of this type`.FYI `Append`,`Append To`,`Assign` are set to `User` `(Basic)` access level.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of the priviliges on those two entities, it sounds as if there is some glitch between the custom entities rights for that user

Comment: Rickard, I have added the screen shot.Users with `Customer` security roll can only read `ProjectStageExternal` entity.But Admin can create/Assign/Append/Associate records of `Project` and `ProjectStageExternel` Entity.

Comment: let me create another question.

Comment: Did the problem occur when a user or an admin created the project?

Comment: When Admin is owner then it works fine, If the owner is other user that problem is occurring.